# singleton usage in multithread

Tags: c++, synchronization

I am reading a book on applied C++ about locking and design.

```
void addRef() { ref++; }
void subRef() { if(--ref == 0) delete this; }
```

> Although a statement  like ref++ looks trivial, there is no guarantee
>   that it is atomic. But before you go and rewrite this code to add
>   locking, you need to know how your application will use it. In this
>   particular example, a bug is created if addRef is called after subRef.
>   The problem is not with missing locks, it is poor design. If an object
>   must persist beyond scope of a thread, it should be created and owned
>   by a different thread that will not go out of scope.

My question on above text is

1. What does author mean by poor design and how this is avoided by "If an object must persist beyond scope of a thread, it should be created and owned by a different thread that will not go out of scope." ? Request to give an example on this.

Comment: `std::atomic` would work as well. but `delete this` is horrible anyways - what good is a reference counter within the object that is counted

Comment: why are you mentioning singleton in your question title while there is nothing to do with it in your actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void thread1work(RefCntObj* refcntObj) 
{
  refcntObj.addRef();
  // any work
  refcntObj.subRef();
}

int main(void) {
  RefCntObj* refcntObj= new RefCntObj(); // I assume the constructor calls addRef()
  std::thread t(thread1work, std::ref(f));
  refcntObj->subRef(); // may be called after thread1Work or before it
}
```

There is no guarantee that the `thread1work` will be called before main's `refcntObj->subRef();`. In such case the object would already be deleted and the pointer invalid.

Answer (score 0):

By poor design of code, the author means a poor construction of classes and methods ; where you place what and how that position makes your code accessible.

> "If an object must persist beyond scope of a thread, it should be created and owned by a different thread that will not go out of scope."

Simply put, the above means that if you have B inside of A(Thread) but you need to use B also in C, than you must remove B from inside the thread(A) and make it independent from it, so you can use it in both A and C.

Answer (score 0):

Who knows?  You'd have to ask the author.  This looks like 
classical reference counting to me: to make it safe, you'd have
to either user a mutex to protect all accesses to `ref`, or make
`ref` some sort of atomic variable.  (C++11 has a whole range of
functions on `std::atomic<int>` which you can use.)

With regards to the quoted text: you can make anything unsafe if
you don't use it right.  If two threads are accessing the same
instance, then `ref` should already be at least 2, so that if
one thread drops the reference, the object will still continue
to exist.  There is no need for any additional thread to
complicate matters.